# robocopy with environment variable will cause 0x10

Tags: environment-variables, task-scheduler, robocopy

I tried this on command line and it will work correctly

```
robocopy /mir /copy:DAT /mot:30  "D:\Source File\file" "E:\Target Directory\backup %DATE:/=-% %time::=-%" /xd "D:\Source File\file\excluded"
```

But after I create a schedule task to run it, I got 0x10 result

It will just run correctly if I remove this part

```
%DATE:/=-% %time::=-%
```

Any suggestion, will help me a lot.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think robocopy would understand how to translate the variable `%DATE:/=-%` or `%time::=-%` natively. Try changing your scheduled task to run `cmd` and call robocopy from there.

```
cmd /c robocopy /mir /copy:DAT /mot:30  "D:\Source File\file" "E:\Target Directory\backup %DATE:/=-% %time::=-%" /xd "D:\Source File\file\excluded"
```